# How to Loop Registry Value in Batchfile

Tags: batch-file

I need help. I want to set all `ConfigFlags"=dword:0000000(0)value` from `ConfigFlags"=dword:000000(20)`.

I want to use cmd to do all of these but here's my problem.

In `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\PCI` there are tons of `HardwareIDS`.
Like:

```
1.VEN_1000&DEV_0054&SUBSYS_197615AD&REV_01
2.VEN_10EC&DEV_5287&SUBSYS_096A1025&REV_01
....
```

inside each `VEN_IDS` there is `4&36677646&0&00E2` this value is not static it change depends on `VEN_IDS`

Like:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\PCI\VEN_10EC&DEV_5287&SUBSYS_096A1025&REV_01\4&36677646&0&00E2 after ConfigFlags.
```

I want to Set all `ConfigFlags inspite` of Different `VEN_IDS` and Class.`

Answer (score 0):

To perform the task, you need to first of all determine the subkeys under: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\PCI`. You can do that directly with the `Query` command of `reg.exe`.

If you perform that command within a `For` loop, you can return each registry key as a variable and pass each to the `Do` portion, which holds your command to `Add` the intended value data.

The following example should assist you:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions

Set "RootKey=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE"
Set "ParentKey=SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\PCI"
Set "ValueName=ConfigFlags"
Set "DataType=REG_DWORD"
Set "DataValue=0x0"

Set "RegCommand=%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe"
Set "FindStrCommand=%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe"

For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('
 %RegCommand% Query "%RootKey%\%ParentKey%" /S /F "%ValueName%" /V
 /T %DataType% 2^>NUL ^| %FindStrCommand% /B "HK"
 ') Do %RegCommand% Add "%%G" /V "%ValueName%" /T %DataType% /D "%DataValue%" /F
```

What it does is pass the full registry key names of each entry which currently holds a value named `ConfigFlags` to another `reg.exe` command, which `/F`orce `Add`s the `REG_DWORD` data `0x00000000`.

*Please note that as this script will be modifying the content of the protected `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` root key, you will need to run it elevated, (as administrator), or as a user with the required write permissions.*

If you open a Command Prompt using the `Run as administrator` option, you could just perform the task as a single line command:

```
@For /F Delims^= %G In ('reg.exe Query HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\PCI /S /F ConfigFlags /V /T REG_DWORD 2^>NUL^|findstr.exe "^HK"')Do @reg.exe Add "%G" /V ConfigFlags /T REG_DWORD /D 0 /F 1>NUL
```

---

If you don't want to just concentrate on `PCI` devices, to include for example: `ACPI`, `DISPLAY`, `HID`, `ROOT`, `SCSI`, `USB` etc., then change `Enum\PCI` to just `Enum`.